# Wordpress malware created fake pages with this kind of URLs /?p=cheap-nhl-jerseys-6850.html

Tags: wordpress, malware, virus

My site got some Wordpress viruses I can't find. Does anyone know how to find the location of virus code in this situation or the directory of this pages. Another problem is that the content of these pages is the same as the home page. Does it duplicate the content of home page or it somehow just changes the url of home page and presents it as separate page that Google indexes.

Comment: is it wordpress.org (self hosted) or wordpress.com ? if it's .org then   try a fresh install of WordPress, theme and plugins. read up on securing your site: permissions, blank index.php in folders, using plugins from wordpress.org site. try some security plugins, check your database is ok too. you make backups right?? you are running the latest version too right?

Answer (score 0):

Export your database and files, make a fresh install of wordpress, re-import your data, install All in One Security plugin and configure it. Then re-install your plugins from wordpress repo, and you can also re-install your theme.

But be carefull because security breach comes certainly from your theme or plugins.